# Python Regex: Finding First and Last Names

Tags: python, regex

I have a bunch of names in a string, and each first + last name is located within '>' and '>'s. So, the string could be, for example `'uselessdataetc<Michael Bloomberg>blahblah<William Handler>blahblah'` and I'd want it to return `'Michael Bloomberg'`, `'William Handler'`

This is the regex I'm using:

```
nameregex = '<([a-z]+|\s)*>'
```

I'm using re.IGNORECASE when using the regex. It's currently only returning last names. So it's returning 'Bloomberg', 'Handler'.

Can anyone see why this is happening?

Answer (score 4):

Search for:

```
r'<([^>]+)>'
```

instead and find anything that is *not* the end character.

Demo:

```
>>> nameregex = re.compile(r'<([^>]+)>')
>>> nameregex.findall('uselessdataetc<Michael Bloomberg>blahblah<William Handler>blahblah')
['Michael Bloomberg', 'William Handler']
```

Your regular expression uses a capturing group around each set of letters *or* whitespace, and only the *last* such match inside the `<...>` angle brackets is returned, as a capturing group is not multiplied even if it matches multiple patterns. `Michael Bloomberg` is 3 matches; `(Michael)( )(Bloomberg)` and only the last such match is returned for the capturing group.

You can make your version work by using:

```
nameregex = '<((?:[a-z]+|\s)*)>'
```

instead, or include the whitespace in the character class and remove the outer wildcard:

```
nameregex = '<([a-z\s]+)>'
```

Comment: Beautiful, and fast response.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
nameregex = r'<([^>]+)>'
```

Comment: That worked! I know ^ means starts with, but I've never heard of the '>'. What does that mean?

Comment: Actually `^` means **not** when inside a character class `[]` so essentially we are looking for `<` then capturing all characters that are not `>` and the closing `>`

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer:

```
nameregex = r'<([^>]+)>'
```

in your case:

```
>>> nameregex = re.compile(r'<([^>]+)>')
>>> nameregex.findall('uselessdataetc<Michael Bloomberg>blahblah<William Handler>blahblah')
['Michael Bloomberg', 'William Handler']
```

or simpler:

```
>>> re.findall(r'<([^>]+)>','uselessdataetc<Michael Bloomberg>blahblah<William Handler>blahblah')
['Michael Bloomberg', 'William Handler']
```